How do I convert a utc time to a timezoned date object where the timezoned time is the same as the utc was
I have a time like this which is selected in a datetimepicker
let time = 2024-04-22T10:00:00.000Z

i want the user to be able to choose a timezone that the time is in as an example europe/helsinki
i want to have a function that can convert that time into the zoned time and the output would be for example
converFromUtcToZoned("2024-04-22T10:00:00.000Z", "europe/helsinki") //output example "2024-04-22T70:00:00.000Z"

I have tried using the date-fns library but havent gotten anyt of those functions to work the way i wouldve wanted and i have tried searching for answers elsewhere.

Did you check the toZonedTime from date-fns-tz?

"2024-04-22T10:00:00.000Z" should convert to "2024-04-22T13:00:00.000GMT+03:00" for Helsinki (i.e. it's 3 hours ahead of UTC at that time and date).

You can use Date.prototype.toLocaleString to format the string with a given timeZone argument.
const formatDateTime = (date: Date, timeZone: string): string =>
  `${date.toLocaleDateString("en-CA", {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "2-digit",
    day: "2-digit",
    timeZone,
  })}T${date.toLocaleTimeString("en-GB", {
    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit",
    second: "2-digit",
    fractionalSecondDigits: 3,
    hour12: false,
    timeZone,
  })}`;

const convertFromUtcToZoned = (date: Date | string, timeZone: string): string =>
  formatDateTime(typeof date === "string" ? new Date(date) : date, timeZone);

const zonedDate = convertFromUtcToZoned(
  "2024-04-22T10:00:00.000Z",
  "europe/helsinki",
);
console.log(zonedDate); // 2024-04-22T13:00:00.000



const formatDateTime = (date, timeZone) => `${date.toLocaleDateString("en-CA", {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "2-digit",
    day: "2-digit",
    timeZone,
})}T${date.toLocaleTimeString("en-GB", {
    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit",
    second: "2-digit",
    fractionalSecondDigits: 3,
    hour12: false,
    timeZone,
})}`;

const convertFromUtcToZoned = (date, timeZone) => formatDateTime(typeof date === "string" ? new Date(date) : date, timeZone);

const zonedDate = convertFromUtcToZoned("2024-04-22T10:00:00.000Z", "europe/helsinki");

console.log(zonedDate); // 2024-04-22T13:00:00.000




This parses a supported format like '2024-04-22T10:00:00.000Z' to a Date, then generates an unsupported format from toLocaleString (ECMA-262 states that the output of toLocaleString need not be parseable) that is passed to the built–in parser to parse back into a Date, then generate another timestamp that isn't the right instant in time. Helsinki has been UTC+3 since the end of March, so 2024-04-22T10:00:00.000Z should convert to 2024-04-22T13:00:00.000GMT+03:00.
